# Flink bundles Apache Beam together and does not show individual tasks blocks

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I have a Beam pipeline running on a Flink runner as shown:

[image]

The whole pipeline in BEAM gets bundled into this block. Why does Flink illustrate it this way?

[image]

Surely the different pardo's in the pipeline steps should be represented by different blocks and workers (as in Google's Dataflow). Is there something that needs to be set up in the Flink runner to show more granular tasks or is the Flink UI built for native Flink code only and this is just the way the UI will deal with a Apache Beam pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

That is operator chaining, which optimises the performance of Flink pipeline. For example,

```
source.filter(...).map(...)...
```

If filter and map has the same parallelism, then Flink chains filter and map operator together internally to reduce the cost of data network transporting, serialisation and deserialisation etc.

On UI, if several operators are chained into one operator, they will be bundled together.

Reference: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups

Answer (score 0):

This is because Flink shows the physical shape of the pipeline, rather than the logical shape (with composite transform nesting and before fusion). Note in particular for a portable pipeline (which covers any non-Java pipelines) Beam does its own fusion in order to avoid ping-ponging elements back and forth between processes.